# Accordion Spacing Issues

Tags: css, wordpress, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have this [test page](http://www.northwestradiology.com/imaging/imaging-category-1/) on a Wordpress website I am working on, where I'm using shortcodes to add in an accordion. It is working fine, except when I open one, the one next to it opens. I somewhat understand why it's doing this, but I can't seem to get around it. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean Accordion?

Comment: What do you want? Because seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Well really an accordion menu usually means all the items are in the same vertical column. The fact you are doing them side by side is kinda of odd. If you want them side by side, you will need to make two separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

For `.accordion-group`, use `display: block;` instead of `display: inline-block;` . and no need for `<br>` tag.